# Angular12 interpolation updating automatically

Tags: angular

I have a Angular12 application that receives data (a very basic timer) from a socket.io server. This data should automatically update on the UI as the timer increases. I used interpolation to display "time= new Date(0,0,0,0,0,0). The variable does update in component.ts, but my UI does not update, it stays at 00:00:00. How can I make this so that my variable "time" (-> component.ts) automaticaly updates on my UI?

Component.ts:

```
import { Component, OnInit, Output, EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';
import { Subject } from 'rxjs';
import { WebsocketService } from './websocket.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  title = 'timerServiceClient';
  time = new Date(0,0,0,0,0,0);
  laps = [""];
  startbtnDisabled = false;


  constructor(private webSocketService: WebsocketService){}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.webSocketService.listen('connectmsg').subscribe((data) => {
      console.log(data)
    })
  }

  onStartTimer() {
    const message = 'Start the timer'
    this.webSocketService.emit('startTimer', message)
    this.startbtnDisabled = true
    this.webSocketService.listen('timer').subscribe((data: number) => {
      console.log(data)
      this.time.setSeconds(data);
    })
  }

  onStopTimer() {
    const message = 'the timer has stopped'
    this.webSocketService.emit('stopTimer', message)
    this.startbtnDisabled = false
  }

  onResetTimer(){
    const message = 'Reset the timer'
    this.webSocketService.emit('resetTimer', message)
  }
```

component.html:

```
<div class="container">

<div id="timerDisplay">
  <span >
  <h1>{{time | date: 'HH:mm:ss'}}</h1>
  </span>
</div>

<hr>
<div class="buttons">
<button mat-raised-button color="primary" disabled="{{startbtnDisabled}}" (click)="onStartTimer()" >Start</button>
<button mat-raised-button color="primary" (click)="onStopTimer()">Stop</button>
<button mat-raised-button color="warn" (click)="onResetTimer()">Reset</button>
<button mat-raised-button color="accent" (click)="onRegisterLap()">Lap</button>
</div>

<mat-list>
  <mat-list-item *ngFor="let lap of laps">{{lap}}</mat-list-item>
</mat-list>
</div>
```

Comment: I believe what you are doing with `this.time.setSeconds(data);` in your callback is wrong. Are you trying to set seconds of the specific minute (0-60 seconds)? Or are you getting an epoch number (approx. 1625082472) back and you're trying to set the date via epoch? If you're doing the latter, I think you can just do `this.time = new Date(data);`

Comment: it seems ngzone doesn't detect changes on websocket events. you can inject cdRef and call `cdRef.detectChanges()` every time you get an event, or you can try to patch ngZone, so it would be able to watch websocket evets. found the desccription on how to do it here https://studiolacosanostra.github.io/2019/09/14/Angular-Zone-WebSocket-Change-detection-Nightmare/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It may be that you need to 'set' the time variable.

```
onStartTimer() {
    const message = 'Start the timer'
    this.webSocketService.emit('startTimer', message)
    this.startbtnDisabled = true
    this.webSocketService.listen('timer').subscribe((data: number) => {
      console.log(data)
      this.time = new Date(this.time.setSeconds(data)); <- SET TIME TO THE NEW VALUE
    })
  }
```

Comment: Updated answer per other's suggestions

Answer (score 0):

You need to update your property time as Brian answered.

In addition, a better approach would be just to create a new Date instance instead of setting seconds:

```
this.time = new Date(secondsReceivedFromWEbSocket);
```